# auto-renew required is not enforced

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions

I have auto-renew required set in my membership types, but users are able to uncheck this and continue to join as non-auto-renew.   I've cleared all caches server and client side.

Since it's required, I'd expect to see a red asterisk next to the checkbox, or see that the checkbox checked, and greyed out.  Neither of these happen.

Is there something else I need to set other than the setting in membership types?

Thanks

Affects versions:

Civi 4.6.23

Civi 4.7.13

Drupal 7

Comment: Have you tried replicating on a demo site to confirm what you are seeing is what is expected? https://civicrm.org/demo

Comment: I could, but not for 4.6 on Drupal. Unfortunately, for 4.6 the only option is Joomla. Probably worth some experimentation on some version.

Comment: I just tried it on 4.7...looks like a bug.

Comment: will you be adding to jira then? if so pls also add as an answer to your own question

Comment: Trying to use hook_civicrm_validateForm as a workaround, but I'm not sure how to access the checkbox data.  I can see it when I print_r($form)...It's in a HTML_QuickForm_checkbox Object and I've no idea how to get to it.

Comment: Maybe try on the dev channel at chat.civicrm.org if you haven't already

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug affecting versions 4.6.23 and 4.7.13.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19608

Comment: This is part of the current  release review - would help if others can 'sign up' and help get fixes for bugs like this tested - https://docs.google.com/document/d/107kGgGCQnsjPlGQqXUqO2P7u1mfdtnJ8EQ8pq_L7mIo/edit